# Trying to reduce LV; unable to fsck

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, lvm

I have a Linux Virtual Machine (hosted by the VM Ware ESXi hypervisor). It has 1 TB drive with the LVM onboard configured ~2 years ago while installing the OS.
The lvs tool output shows how the physical volume has been divided into the logical volumes.

```
lvs
LV   VG   Attr       LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log
Cpy%Sync Convert   
home part -wi-a----- <965,12g                      
root part -wi-ao----   50,00g                                         
swap part -wi-ao----   <7,88g
```

I need to resize (extend) the root partition (the logical volume in the VLM) because I slowly run out of space there. To achieve that I have to reduce the size of /home volume which is quite large and there is lots of free room there.

The procedure of reducing the volume says that first I have to unmount the /dev/mapper/part-home from /home.

```
umount -v /home 
umount: /home (/dev/mapper/part-home) unmounted
```

Then I have to fsck the unmounted volume:

```
e2fsck -ff /dev/mapper/part-home 
e2fsck 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
e2fsck_open2: Bad magic number in super-block 
e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks... 
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/mapper/part-home

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the
superblock is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an
alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
```

but - as you can see - I get an error message.

So I use another tool which simulates creating a filesystem on the logical volume giving me some hints about the location of the backup superblocks.

```
mkfs.ext4 -n /dev/mapper/part-home  
mke2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
Filesystem label= 
OS Type: Linux 
Block size=4096 (log=2) 
Fragment size=4096 (log=2) 
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks 
63250432 i-nodes, 252999680 blocks 
12649984 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user 
First data block=0 
Maximum filesystem blocks=2401239040
7721 block groups 32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 i-nodes per group 
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
     32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
     4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
     102400000, 214990848
```

So I use the following command to use the backup superblock but get another error message. I get the same using each number given by the previous one 32768, 98304 and so forth.

```
e2fsck -b 71663616 -B 4096 /dev/mapper/part-home 
e2fsck 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013) 
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/mapper/part-home

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the
superblock is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an
alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
```

Can you, please, help me shrinking the part-home volume? Let me add that once mounted everything works great. I can see and list and cat all the files stored in it.

Comment: Hi. The solution turns out to be trival.  I have made a fool of myself. I am embarrassed. I do not know why I have not figured it out myself earlier. As you can see below, the filesystem on /home volume is xfs instead of ext (4, in fact) as I assumed.

/dev/mapper/rhel-home on /home type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)

Thanks, Michael Young, for helping me out in another thread on another forum.